# Do I have to pay council tax if I rent for 6 months?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I'm not a student, I'm a postdoc and unfortunately I need to pay tax.

If I rent a property by myself for 6 whole months, do I need to pay council tax on it? Do I get any discounts at all?

I read somewhere (but can't find it again) that the landlord needs to pay it if it's less than 6 months.

Comment: Can't vouch for the UK,  but generally taxes on housing are paid by the owner on this side of the puddle. Of course that just means your share has been built into your rent...

Comment: @keshlam: Not on this side of the pond, sadly. Unless it's specified in the tenancy agreement, it's the tenant's responsibility.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your tenancy agreement says otherwise, then yes, you are responsible for the council tax.

However, if you live on your own, [you're entitled to a 25% discount](https://www.gov.uk/council-tax/who-has-to-pay). This isn't automatic, so be sure to mention it to the council when you get your account set up.

Comment: 'House in multiple occupation': the landlord pays the council tax. A house in multiple occupation is a property which was originally constructed or subsequently adapted for occupation by persons who do not constitute a single household, or a property which is inhabited by a person or persons who either only have a licence to occupy part of the property or who only pay rent for part of the property.